# Consistent client side password validation rules when using AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

When using User Pools for Authentication in AWS Cognito, a password policy is configured. This policy is the rules which bind the creation of password.

In the UI, these rules have to be re-written to do client side validations. Is there a way to synchronize the client side rules with the cognito user pool rules.

One way I can think of is using CloudFormation to create a UserPool and have it fetch the rules from a rules file, which is then used during the build to update the validation rules in the UI.

Is there a more refined way to achieve this?

Comment: Most password policies don't change much over time, do you have a use case where this changes much?  Or are you trying to manage the ui for several user pools with different password policies?

Comment: Yes, I am designing a multi-tenant system, which will have different user pools and hence different password policies.

Answer (score 2):

The password policy of a user pool can be fetched programmatically.

Example output:

{
MinimumLength: 8,
RequireUppercase: true,
RequireLowercase: true,
RequireNumbers: true,
RequireSymbols: true
}

```js
const identityServiceProvider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION
});

/*
Retrieve the password policy of the Cognito user pool.
*/
exports.getPasswordPolicy = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    identityServiceProvider.describeUserPool({
      "UserPoolId": process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID
    }, (error, data) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        if (data && data.UserPool && data.UserPool.Policies && data.UserPool.Policies.PasswordPolicy) {
          resolve(data.UserPool.Policies.PasswordPolicy);
        }
        else {
          reject(new Error('Unable to fetch password policy'));
        }
      }
    });
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing out of box to help you here. Since you likely need to pass the user pool id into your javascript, I would store this information alongside the user pool id in a mapping.  When you need to serve a page for tenant X use the mapping to lookup tenant X's user pool id and password policy.

If you are using cloudformation, you could output the password policy as an output or directly reference it as an input when you build the resource that serves the tenant.